# Putting Restrictions On Those Who Close/Edit/Move To Chat -- Again

Tags: discussion, edits, chat, vote-to-close

As I suspected would happen, my original thread on restricting close, edit, and move to chat was closed (AND deleted).

I think statistics should be kept on those who do this, and if enough of us lowly posters disagree with what they were doing, we should have a way to identify and restrict individual c/e/mtc people.

I'm not saying I should unilaterally be able to implement these sort of restrictions -- that why there would have to be a "nomination" and vote.  Call it checks and balances.  And I never meant to limit this to IPS Meta either; I just happened to be on IPS SE when I submitted the original proposal.

Why are c/e/mtc people so afraid to let this topic stay open and be publicly discussed?

Comment: Aren't those people generally moderators?

Comment: I suppose.  But even moderators should have to answer for their actions.

Comment: Are you asking why your previous post was closed and deleted? Or are you after a discussion on closing/editing and moving comments to chat? Your title seems to suggest the latter, while your posts reads more like you're unsure why your question got closed?

Comment: Also, if you want to discuss the use of close votes, edits and moving of comments to chat, could you name some examples? Why should there be restrictions, do you have any data suggesting this is needed?

Comment: Maybe the topic isn't so well suited for all members on the site you posted it on? Did you consider the topic itself could be the problem, instead of the moderation actions applied to it?

Comment: Didn't we discuss this on your last question? Didn't the votes indicate that users disagreed?

Comment: My post was referring to threads in general.  But my post about that was closed and deleted, which I also take exception to.  Are the powers-that-be so afraid to let this issue be discussed?

Comment: @Modus Tollens -- and how many of those voters were precisely the ones I've been talking about?

Comment: @Jennifer Maybe I remember it wrongly, but you didn't interact with other users on your last question, right? Maybe that's why it was deleted.

Comment: @Jennifer it's really, really difficult to address this on main meta. Posting it here implies there is a network wide problem with this happening, something that should be addressed on a network wide level. If you really want to make such a case, perhaps it's better to start smaller and discuss this with specific examples of things that were closed, edited or moved to chat while they shouldn't have been one some per-site meta's of the sites you're active on. If there's actually a consensus there, then perhaps you can move it up to a feature request on MSE?

Comment: Right now, a lot of people are just likely to go 'Well, that's just like... your opinion'. Not everyone is likely to see the problem the way your post is written right now, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah, examples or it didn’t happen I’m afraid

Comment: This question seems unclear at best. There are already methods of addressing the things you discuss. And users already *can* influence questions and answers through their earned privileges. (Is this only related to chat?) It's not really at all clear what your issue is or how you're proposing to address it.

Comment: [there are 3 resultsets in my query](https://data.stackexchange.com/interpersonal/query/925518) to build up your case against the users that use their privileges wrongly.

Comment: @rene So... the mods? ;)

Comment: @Catija you know who y'll are ... ;)

Comment: @Jennifer: "*Why are c/e/mtc people so afraid to let this topic stay open and be publicly discussed?*" Because there's nothing to discuss. Our policies are not going to be changed due to one user being disgruntled over comment threads being moved to chat or having poor questions closed or having their questions edited. If you have a specific complaint about a specific moderator action, that can be handled. But simply declaring that users should have power over moderators beyond what they currently have, without any foundation or evidence, is not going to lead to anything useful.

Comment: This question will likely be deleted as well. If you want to actually discuss this, them you need to bring something constructive to the table. Asserting that the deletion is censorship does nothing but get you dismissed.

Answer (score 15):

Most of these checks and balances already exist.

### Closing

- Anyone with more than 3,000 reputation can vote to reopen
- Anyone can edit the post (less than 2,000 reputation and it'll have to be reviewed); editing will put the post in the queue to be assessed for reopening
- Anyone with more than 5 reputation (make 2 edits to get 5 rep) can post to meta to request that post be reopened (and the original poster doesn't need any rep to post on meta about their specific post)
- Anyone with more than 15 reputation can flag the post for moderator attention (not to reopen) if something particularly egregious is going on
- Closing is completely public and can be assessed by the community at large

### Editing

- The post owner can roll back an edit (if you feel the need to do this twice flag the post instead)
- Anyone with 2,000 reputation can roll back an edit
- The post owner can reject suggested edits made by people with less than 2,000 reputation
- Edits made by people with less than 2,000 reputation must be assessed by their peers
- Edits are completely public and can be assessed by the community at large

### Move to chat

This only applies to comments, which are considered ephemeral and subject to deletion at any time. Don't put anything permanent in comments, that's what answering and editing is for.

Comments being moved to chat can be viewed by everyone and any concerns raised by both flagging (15 reputation) and making a polite request on meta (5 reputation) for the reasoning.

### Conclusion

In short, there is a powerful set of tools available to users and non-users at all reputation levels to politely request review of the actions of others. I personally don't see the need for a separate set of tools when these already exist.

I'm saying this with a lot of reputation across Stack Exchange; I may well be missing something. I've found that an unemotional, cogently argued case with statistics to back it up will usually be received well on meta. The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) can be used to find everything that you're concerned about — it can't be used to query deleted posts though.

Comment: Note: PostsWithDeleted in SEDE has *some* data on deleted posts, but there's some heavy anonymization inherent, so your last parenthetical is only half right.